# Java8 calculate average of list of objects in the map

Tags: java-8, java-stream

Initial data:

```
public class Stats {
    int passesNumber;
    int tacklesNumber;

    public Stats(int passesNumber, int tacklesNumber) {
        this.passesNumber = passesNumber;
        this.tacklesNumber = tacklesNumber;
    }

    public int getPassesNumber() {
        return passesNumber;
    }

    public void setPassesNumber(int passesNumber) {
        this.passesNumber = passesNumber;
    }

    public int getTacklesNumber() {
        return tacklesNumber;
    }

    public void setTacklesNumber(int tacklesNumber) {
        this.tacklesNumber = tacklesNumber;
    }
} 

Map<String, List<Stats>> statsByPosition = new HashMap<>();
statsByPosition.put("Defender", Arrays.asList(new Stats(10, 50), new Stats(15, 60), new Stats(12, 100)));
statsByPosition.put("Attacker", Arrays.asList(new Stats(80, 5), new Stats(90, 10)));
```

I need to calculate an average of Stats by position. So result should be a map with the same keys, however values should be aggregated to single Stats object (List should be reduced to single Stats object)

```
{
  "Defender" => Stats((10 + 15 + 12) / 3, (50 + 60 + 100) / 3),
  "Attacker" => Stats((80 + 90) / 2, (5 + 10) / 2)
}
```

Comment: What did you try so far? I guess `Stats` have getter and setters for their values?

Comment: Yes, there are getters and setters which I forgot to mention

Comment: Thx, I have edited my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's anything new in Java8 that could really help in solving this problem, at least not efficiently.

If you look carefully at all new APIs, then you will see that majority of them are aimed at providing more powerful primitives for working on single values and their sequences - that is, on sequences of `double`, `int`, `? extends Object`, etc.

For example, to compute an average on sequence on `double`, JDK introduces a new class - `DoubleSummaryStatistics` which does an obvious thing - collects a summary over arbitrary sequence of `double` values.
I would actually suggest that you yourself go for similar approach: make your own `StatsSummary` class that would look along the lines of this:

```
// assuming this is what your Stats class look like:
class Stats {
  public final double a ,b; //the two stats
  public Stats(double a, double b) {
    this.a = a; this.b = b;
  }
}

// summary will go along the lines of:
class StatsSummary implements Consumer<Stats> {
  DoubleSummaryStatistics a, b; // summary of stats collected so far
  StatsSummary() {
    a = new DoubleSummaryStatistics();
    b = new DoubleSummaryStatistics();
  }

  // this is how we collect it:
  @Override public void accept(Stats stat) {
    a.accept(stat.a); b.accept(stat.b);
  }
  public void combine(StatsSummary other) {
    a.combine(other.a); b.combine(other.b);
  }

  // now for actual methods that return stuff. I will implement only average and min
  // but rest of them are not hard
  public Stats average() {
    return new Stats(a.getAverage(), b.getAverage());
  }
  public Stats min() {
    return new Stats(a.getMin(), b.getMin());
  }
}
```

Now, above implementation will actually allow you to express your proper intents when using `Stream`s and such: by building a rigid API and using classes available in JDK as building blocks, you get less errors overall.

However, if you only want to compute average once somewhere and don't need anything else, coding this class is a little overkill, and here's a quick-and-dirty solution:

```
Map<String, Stats> computeAverage(Map<String, List<Stats>> statsByPosition) {
  Map<String, Stats> averaged = new HashMap<>();
  statsByPosition.forEach((position, statsList) -> {
    averaged.put(position, averageStats(statsList));
  });
  return averaged;
}

Stats averageStats(Collection<Stats> stats) {
  double a, b;
  int len = stats.size();
  for(Stats stat : stats) {
    a += stat.a;
    b += stat.b;
  }
  return len == 0d? new Stats(0,0) : new Stats(a/len, b/len);
}
```

Comment: If you pass an empty Collection of stats, your code will crash

Comment: @PascalSchneider Latter one will, yes. I wasn't really making sure it didn't have any errors, that one was sort of an alternative approach. I'll fix it though.

Answer (score 1):

There is probably a cleaner solution with Java 8, but this works well and isn't too complex:

```
Map<String, Stats> newMap = new HashMap<>();

statsByPosition.forEach((key, statsList) -> {
    newMap.put(key, new Stats(
         (int) statsList.stream().mapToInt(Stats::getPassesNumber).average().orElse(0),
         (int) statsList.stream().mapToInt(Stats::getTacklesNumber).average().orElse(0))
    );
});
```

The functional `forEach` method lets you iterate over every `key` `value` pair of your given map.

You just put a new entry in your map for the averaged values. There you take the `key` you have already in your given map. The new value is a new `Stats`, where the arguments for the constructor are calculated directly.

Just take the value of your old map, which is the `statsList` in the `forEach` function, map the values from the given stats to `Integer` value with `mapToInt` and use the `average` function.

This function returns an `OptionalDouble` which is nearly the same as `Optional<Double>`. Preventing that anything didn't work, you use its `orElse()` method and pass a default value (like `0`). Since the average values are `double` you have to cast the value to `int`.

As mentioned, there doubld probably be a even shorter version, using `reduce`.

Comment: It might lead to side effect - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html . Please use `Collectors.toMap` instead of populating new map from a `forEach` loop

Comment: @AntonBalaniuc, or cource is leads to side effect - that's the whole purpose of `forEach()` methods, they are very rarely pure, and pure foreach only useful on mutable data. Also, please explain what using `Collectors.toMap` will give in this example (in this case it just hides away what actually happens). Were you talking about using `toMap` collector over `Stream<Map.Entry<>>`?

Comment: @M.Prokhorov, well it is not recommended to use `foreach` to  populate data structure. It is not thread safe and might produce incorrect result. You can read more in the link above.  What we can use here is `Collectors.toMap`

Comment: `statsByPosition.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
                entry -> entry.getKey(),
                entry -> new Stats(
                        (int) entry.getValue().stream().mapToInt(Stats::getPassesNumber).average().orElse(0),
                        (int) entry.getValue().stream().mapToInt(Stats::getTacklesNumber).average().orElse(0))
                )
        );`

Comment: @AntonBalaniuc, it's not thread safe, but there also is no threads involved other than `Thread.currentThread()`, so having something that is not thread-safe is completely fine. I would still stand by my initial judgement in that making use of streams and collectors there is an overkill. I also think that if threading is involved, then we should use composite collector based on my design of `StatsSummary` class seen [there](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42557741/7470253), like this: `collect(Collector.of(StatsSummary::new, StatsSummary::accept, StatsSummary::combine, StatsSummary::average))`

Comment: @M.Prokhorov well, I guess if it is not recommended by `jdk` authors, we should probably listen to them, and avoid usage of side effects. Please follow this link. There is a side-effect section - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html. Generally `reduction` functions are more preferable then `forEach`

Answer (score 0):

You might as well use custom collector. Let's add the following methods to `Stats` class:

```
 public Stats() {

 }

 public void accumulate(Stats stats) {
     passesNumber += stats.passesNumber;
     tacklesNumber += stats.tacklesNumber;
 }

 public Stats combine(Stats acc) {
     passesNumber += acc.passesNumber;
     tacklesNumber += acc.tacklesNumber;
     return this;
 }


 @Override
 public String toString() {
     return "Stats{" +
             "passesNumber=" + passesNumber +
             ", tacklesNumber=" + tacklesNumber +
             '}';
 }
```

Now we can use `Stats` in `collect` method:

```
System.out.println(statsByPosition.entrySet().stream().collect(
        Collectors.toMap(
            entity -> entity.getKey(),
            entity -> {
                Stats entryStats = entity.getValue().stream().collect(
                        Collector.of(Stats::new, Stats::accumulate, Stats::combine)
                ); // get stats for each map key. 

                // get average
                entryStats.setPassesNumber(entryStats.getPassesNumber() / entity.getValue().size());
                // get average
                entryStats.setTacklesNumber(entryStats.getTacklesNumber() / entity.getValue().size());

            return entryStats;
        }
))); // {Attacker=Stats{passesNumber=85, tacklesNumber=7}, Defender=Stats{passesNumber=12, tacklesNumber=70}}
```

Answer (score 0):

*If* java-9 is available and *StreamEx*, you could do :

```
    public static Map<String, Stats> third(Map<String, List<Stats>> statsByPosition) {

    return statsByPosition.entrySet().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.getKey(),
                    Collectors.flatMapping(e -> e.getValue().stream(),
                            MoreCollectors.pairing(
                                    Collectors.averagingDouble(Stats::getPassesNumber),
                                    Collectors.averagingDouble(Stats::getTacklesNumber),
                                    (a, b) -> new Stats(a, b)))));
}
```